# Using result of SELECT to assign multiple WHERE conditions

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, dry

Let's say I have a dummy database with civilians. Every row contains their name, city, street, street number, and job. A minimal example to generate a database in SQLite:

```py
import sqlite3
from pathlib import Path


def main():
    build_cmd = """CREATE TABLE civs (
    name TEXT,
    city TEXT,
    street TEXT,
    snumber INTEGER,
    job TEXT) """

    pdb = Path("dummy.db")
    if pdb.exists():
        pdb.unlink()
    conn = sqlite3.connect(str("dummy.db"))

    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(build_cmd)

    insert_cmds = """
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO civs VALUES ('john', 'dublin', 'butchers_street', '42', 'butcher');
    INSERT INTO civs VALUES ('marie', 'london', 'butchers_street', '3', 'baker');
    INSERT INTO civs VALUES ('keith', 'london', 'camel_road', '7', 'carpenter');
    INSERT INTO civs VALUES ('anna', 'dublin', 'butchers_street', '9', 'butcher');
    INSERT INTO civs VALUES ('steve', 'london', 'maceys_alley', '1', 'blacksmith');
    INSERT INTO civs VALUES ('beth', 'dublin', 'butchers_street', '68', 'grocer');
    INSERT INTO civs VALUES ('lisa', 'dublin', 'church_street', '32', 'nun');
    COMMIT;
    """

    cur.executescript(insert_cmds)
    cur.close()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now, I want to retrieve all the people that live in the same city and street as `john`. When I just want to check for `street`, I can make it work like this:

```sql
SELECT civs.name, civs.city, civs.street
FROM
    civs
WHERE
    street = (
    SELECT street
    FROM civs
    WHERE
        name = 'john'
    )
```

But this of course will also return marie, who lives in London, not in Dublin.

| name | city | street |
| --- | --- | --- |
| marie | london | butchers_street |
| john | dublin | butchers_street |
| beth | dublin | butchers_street |
| anna | dublin | butchers_street |

So I tried the following which does not work:

```sql
SELECT civs.name, civs.city, civs.street
FROM
    civs
WHERE
    street, city = (
    SELECT street, city
    FROM civs
    WHERE
        name = 'john'
    )
```

The following does work, but it is not very [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Is there a better way?

```sql
SELECT civs.name, civs.city, civs.street
FROM
    civs
WHERE
    street = (
    SELECT street
    FROM civs
    WHERE
        name = 'john'
    )
    AND city = (
    SELECT city
    FROM civs
    WHERE
        name = 'john'
    )
```

***Note***: efficiency is important for me. You can assume that it is a cold table and that all columns are indexed.

Comment: `WHERE (street, city) = (SELECT street, city FROM civs WHERE name = 'john')` will do

Comment: In most cases JOINs are faster than sub-queries and it is very rare for a sub-query to be faster.

Comment: @Ahmed this is not a correlated subquery. It is executed only once and it should perform better than a join.