# Refer to SELECT outside of JOIN

Tags: python, sqlite, join

I got some great help in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72328258/using-result-of-select-to-assign-multiple-where-conditions). This one builds on top of that. I want to retrieve information of the joined queries but I do not know if that is possible in SQL.

Here is a dummy database with civilians. Every row contains their name, city, street, street number, and job. Minimal example to generate DataBase in SQLite:

```py
import sqlite3
from pathlib import Path


def main():
    build_cmd = """CREATE TABLE civs (
    name TEXT,
    city TEXT,
    street TEXT,
    snumber INTEGER,
    job TEXT) """

    pdb = Path("dummy.db")
    if pdb.exists():
        pdb.unlink()
    conn = sqlite3.connect(str("dummy.db"))

    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(build_cmd)

    insert_cmds = """
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO civs VALUES ('john', 'dublin', 'butchers_street', '42', 'butcher');
    INSERT INTO civs VALUES ('marie', 'london', 'butchers_street', '3', 'baker');
    INSERT INTO civs VALUES ('keith', 'london', 'camel_road', '7', 'carpenter');
    INSERT INTO civs VALUES ('anna', 'dublin', 'butchers_street', '9', 'butcher');
    INSERT INTO civs VALUES ('steve', 'london', 'maceys_alley', '1', 'blacksmith');
    INSERT INTO civs VALUES ('beth', 'dublin', 'butchers_street', '68', 'grocer');
    INSERT INTO civs VALUES ('lisa', 'dublin', 'church_street', '32', 'nun');
    COMMIT;
    """

    cur.executescript(insert_cmds)
    cur.close()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Let's say I want to retrieve *in one row* (so one row per person who lives in a John's street). I use "a" John, because theoretically you can of course have multiple Johns.

- the street where a John lives
- the city where a John lives
- the job of a John
- the name of a person who lives in the same street and city as a John
- the job of a person who lives in the same street and city as a John

I got this far, which retrieves the information of the main query.

```sql
SELECT
    civs.street, civs.city, civs.name, civs.job
FROM civs
JOIN
    (SELECT city, street
     FROM civs
     WHERE name='john') jcivs

    ON civs.street = jcivs.street
        AND civs.city = jcivs.city
```

which gives

| street | city | name | job |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| butchers_street | dublin | anna | butcher |
| butchers_street | dublin | beth | grocer |
| butchers_street | dublin | john | butcher |

but "the job of a John" is sorely missing *and* I get john as a separate row, which I do not want as we are interested in neighbors of John. So I am not sure how I can refer to `jcivs` from my outermost SELECT. So this does not work as `jcivs` does not exist for the outer SELECT:

```sql
SELECT
    civs.street, civs.city, jcivs.job, civs.name, civs.job
```

Expected result:

| street | city | johnsjob | name | job |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| butchers_street | dublin | butcher | anna | butcher |
| butchers_street | dublin | butcher | beth | grocer |

**NOTE**: efficiency is important for me. You can assume that it is a cold table and that all columns are indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create an `id` column because SQLite provides for every table a [`rowid`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) column (which is the actual primary key of the table).

Do a simple self join like this:

```
SELECT c1.*
FROM civs c1 INNER JOIN civs c2
ON (c2.city, c2.street) = (c1.city, c1.street) AND c2.rowid <> c1.rowid
WHERE c2.name = 'john';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=997def77bce11803dc8d89bf0d5f10ff).

Comment: Thanks! Any (dis)advantage of doing the WHERE at the end? In @Cole's example, if I understood correctly, the subquery is restricted to `name = 'john` before the join, in yours this restriction is imposed on the joined table. My intuition tells me that Cole's is therefore faster as it joins one large and one small table, and yours joins two large tables and only then filters on the name. Is that intuition correct?

Comment: @BramVanroy in the demo link I provide in my answer you can see the plan of the 2 queries where you can check the difference.

Answer (score 1):

This should be one approach:

```sql
WITH civs2 AS (
  SELECT civs.*, row_number() OVER () as id FROM civs
 )
 SELECT
    civs2.street, civs2.city, jcivs.job, civs2.name, civs2.job
FROM civs2
JOIN
    (SELECT city, street, job, id
     FROM civs2
     WHERE name='john') jcivs

    ON civs2.street = jcivs.street
        AND civs2.city = jcivs.city
        AND civs2.id <> jcivs.id
```

From your query, we:

1. add the job to the *jcivs* subquery; and
2. Demonstrate the use of an ID by creating a CTE with a ID based on row number. Then, we make sure `civs.id <> jcivs.id`

If you had an ID to your table, that might be more efficient as we could add this to the join `civs.id <> jcivs.id`.

Comment: D'oh, I just now realise that I was indeed not including `job` in the subquery. Can you write the full query with `civs.id <> jcivs.id`? It can help me understand better how to incorporate that. Assuming that there is a unique identifier `id` for every citizen.

Comment: See edit. I created an ID to demonstrate as well.